# I have written this code but, it is not allowing me to use the builder method inside ChangeNotifierProvider? i dont know, how to get rid of this?

Tags: flutter

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:learningflutter5h/screens/product_detail_screen.dart';
import 'package:learningflutter5h/screens/products_overview_screen.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import './providers/products.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  ChangeNotifierProvider(
    //my builder is not running here

          builder:(ctx)=>Products(),
          child: MaterialApp(
            title: 'My Shop',
            theme: ThemeData(
              primarySwatch: Colors.purple,
              accentColor: Colors.deepOrange,
              fontFamily: 'Lato',
            ),
            home: ProductsOverviewScreen(),
            routes: {ProductDetailScreen.routName: (ctx) => ProductDetailScreen()},
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can use `create`

code snippet

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<Product>(
      create: (context) => Product(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

    void main() => runApp(MyApp());

    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return ChangeNotifierProvider<Product>(
          create: (context) => Product(),
          child: MaterialApp(
            home: Scaffold(
              appBar: AppBar(title: Text('My App')),
              body: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                      color: Colors.green[200],
                      child: Consumer<Product>(
                        builder: (context, myModel, child) {
                          return RaisedButton(
                            child: Text('Do something'),
                            onPressed: () {
                              myModel.doSomething();
                            },
                          );
                        },
                      )),
                  Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(35),
                    color: Colors.blue[200],
                    child: Consumer<Product>(
                      builder: (context, myModel, child) {
                        return Text(myModel.someValue);
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }

    class Product with ChangeNotifier {
      String someValue = 'Hello';

      void doSomething() {
        someValue = 'Goodbye';
        print(someValue);
        notifyListeners();
      }
    }
```